# Youtube API - find who a comment is replying to (replies to non top-level comments)

Tags: google-api, youtube-api

I want to find when a comment is made as a reply to another comment. The goal is to find discussions, which I've arbitrarily defined as 2 people replying to each other 3 or more times.

Unfortunately, `YouTube currently supports replies only for top-level comments.`[<sup>1</sup>](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/comments/list#filter-parameters) Which means I can't simply use the API.

I thought that perhaps I could look through the text of the comment and find a link to the original author. However, it seems that the original author is just worked in as text.

`+random guy Nobody has to take responsibility for a decision they were forced to make.`

Does anyone have a solution to this? Perhaps there is another API that can deal with youtube comments. (ie Google Plus, I believe it handles notifications when someone replies to you).

Comment: Well, you can use the [Comments: insert](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/comments/insert) to create a reply in an existing comment. But, for getting this specific comment, I think this is not yet supported thru the API.

Comment: yeah :/ what I'm doing right now is going through the comments and saving the authors names. Then going through the comments again and seeing if an author name appears in the text. It's very flawed due to names like `M` and inconsistencies between using `+Name ` and just `Name` in responses (right now searching the `+name` notation, missing a lot of replies though)